# Strange issue with @font-face query

Tags: css

Am using the following code to display H1 items in a special font.

```
@font-face {
font-family: 'Serif-semi-bold';
src: url('http://www.jaguarseascouts.org.uk/wp-content/themes/molesey/fonts/TheSerifSemiBold-Plain.ttf'); /* IE9 Compat Modes */ 
}
```

Displays fine in IE, Firefox etc but looks very grainy and poor in Chrome.

Why would this be?

Many thanks

Comment: The font file referred to is not available without logging in. Besides, the code posted is incomplete (a `@font-face` alone does not do anything), and “vert grainy and poor” is not an objective problem description.

Answer (score 1):

Most modern browsers use .woff fonts, so you may want to include that one too. On the other side, Chrome usually does a really bad job as rendering fonts.

Answer (score 0):

There are ways to clean fonts in most browsers now.

Insert this into your CSS and this will help most fonts:

```
html {
  text-rendering: optimizeLegibility !important;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased !important;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
}
```

If that particular font is problematic, you can download it, upload it and convert it at fontsquirrel.com - it will give you code and multiple different font formats after conversion.